# python 1 particular thread does not return when it hits an exception

Tags: python

i have this code in my main script for starting threads from an array. i have different code in python scripts for different threads to work from. there is 1 particular code that i don't understand why when i hit an exception it seems to hang the entire program/script i have...

```
import threading #(of course)

def start_threads(threads)
    for t in threads:
        t.start()
    for t in threads:
        t.join()
    return

threads = []

thread1 = threading.Thread(target=start_test1,args=(self,))
thread1.daemon = True
threads.append(thread1)

thread2 = threading.Thread(target=start_test2,args=(self,))
thread2.daemon = True
threads.append(thread2)

start_threads(threads)
```

So the code for thread1 will never cause my main program/script to halt when it hits any exceptions. for some reason the code in thread2 does. i am doing a try/except in the code for either thread so i don't know why thread2 wont return properly.

the code inside thread2 is similar to following:

```
try:
    print('starting thread2')
    some_function(options, parameters, etc)
    print('thread2 complete')
except Exception as e:
    print('error running thread2')
    print('msg: %s' % e)
```

I even added a "return" after the last print line in the exception, when i debug after the last print line in or if i place a return there, nothing happens, meaning walking the lines seem ok, but it never returns to my main code to exit program/script. i see the print messages on console, but my code should be exiting the main program with another message.

Comment: Does it ever print `thread2 complete` or `error running thread2`? btw. why are you turning your threads into daemons when later on you're waiting for them to join your main thread?

Comment: since this is a code-specific question, please edit and add the full code (or a simplified version of it) so we could help..

Comment: @zwer , no it does not, so the some_function is part of a python lib for an sdk/package. so some_function encounters an exception or issue, so it then enters the except clause and prints both those msgs but never exits my program... i even did debugging so that this "problem thread" was the only thread running.

Comment: @nutmeg64 i thought i was giving a simplified version :)

Comment: Wait, if it does not print `error running thread2` how do you know it entered your exception clause? If it does, then your problem is somewhere else in `start_test2` which we cannot know without you showing it.

Comment: it does print "error runnning thread2" , i thought that meant some_function is done now because it hit exception, so shouldn't the thread end?